# Convert a list to a JSON Object in erlang (mochijson)

Tags: json, list, erlang

i would really appreciate any help.
I would like to convert this list

```
[[{id1,1},{id2,2},{id3,3},{id4,4}],[{id1,5},{id2,6},{id3,7},{id4,8}],[...]]
```

to a JSON object.
Need some inspiration :) 
please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you asked for inspiration, I can immagine two directions you can take

1. You can write code to hand-role your own JSON which, if your need is modest enough, can be a very light-weight and appropriate solution. It would be pretty simple Erlang to take that one data-structure and convert it to the JSON.

   "[[{\"id1\":1},{\"id2\":2},{\"id3\":3},{\"id4\":4}],[{\"id1\":5},{\"id2\":6} {\"id3\":7},{\"id4\":8}]]"
2. You can produce a data-structure that mochiweb's mochijson:encode/1 and decode/1 can handle. I took your list and hand coded it to JSON, getting:

   X = "[[{\"id1\":1},{\"id2\":2},{\"id3\":3},{\"id4\":4}],[{\"id1\":5},{\"id2\":6},{\"id3\":7},{\"id4\":8}]]".

then I used mochison:decode(X) to see what structure mochiweb uses to represent JSON (too lazy to look at the documentation).

```
Y = mochijson:decode(X).
{array,[{array,[{struct,[{"id1",1}]},
                {struct,[{"id2",2}]},
                {struct,[{"id3",3}]},
                {struct,[{"id4",4}]}]},
        {array,[{struct,[{"id1",5}]},
                {struct,[{"id2",6}]},
                {struct,[{"id3",7}]},
                {struct,[{"id4",8}]}]}]}
```

So, if you can create this slightly more elaborate data structure then the one you are using, then you can get the JSON by using mochijson:encode/1. Here is an example imbeddied in an io:format statement so that it prints it as a string -- often you would use the io_lib:format/X depending on your application.

```
io:format("~s~n",[mochijson:encode(Y)]).
[[{"id1":1},{"id2":2},{"id3":3},{"id4":4}],[{"id1":5},{"id2":6},{"id3":7},{"id4":8}]]
```

Comment: Thank you. Now you got me thinking. Is this array representation actually a vild JSON Document ? It seems to me that X is actually representation of several documents a tupel or am i wrong?

Comment: I believe X is valid Json, as I understand it's grammar(http://www.json.org/), Json can be nested

Comment: http://www.json.org has a visual version of the grammar that is really clear. But, Json objects absolutely can contain Json objects just as XML can contain XML

Comment: X is a valid JSON string. In case of doubt, I find http://jsonlint.com/ super handy for validating + pretty printing JSON strings.

Comment: You should probably want to use mochiweb's mochijson2 module as it uses a mor convenient representation of json in the erlang side. E.g. json arrays are just erlang lists, not those awkward {array, list()} tuples.